# How to deal with the textures of multiple imported .obj files?

Tags: texturing

So, i am trying to make a scene, with blender. But i import a custom character model. And check texture solid, to get the texture of the character to show. BUT then i upload another .OBJ file, and with texture solid enabled it doesn't show it, but it shows my character model. I have to uncheck texture solid, to get the other .OBJ files texture to show!! I really need help, it is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Could you pack the .blend and [upload it](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)?

Comment: here 

[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=745" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/745/)

Comment: Please someone help?

Comment: "BUT then i upload another .OBJ file, and with texture solid enabled it doesn't show it, but it shows my character model." Doesn't show what? The model or the texture? Please be specific about your problem and what you want to do. The first thing I noticed about your .blend is that *your character's texture files are all missing*, so he just shows up all magenta. Do his textures show for you? If so you need to pack your .blend (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and re-post it. Secondly, *the weapon has no textures* but is comprised of 127 separate pieces! You'll want to Join these.